# C# - OK button dont running whereas there's no error (LINQ to SQL classes)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am a newbie in C#, I want to ask why the OK button don't running when I press it? There is an error message. Here is my code for Form Data, that is contains <kbd>OK</kbd> button:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace Bab_8___LINQ_to_SQL_Classes
{
    public partial class DataForm : Form
    {
        Person _temporaryPerson;

        public Person TemporaryPerson {
            get {
                return _temporaryPerson;
            }
        }

        public DataForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = "Add New Person";
            _temporaryPerson = new Person();
        }

        public DataForm(Person person)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Text = "Edit Person Data";
            _temporaryPerson = person;

            txtName.Text = TemporaryPerson.Name;
            txtAddress.Text = TemporaryPerson.Address;
            txtPhone.Text = TemporaryPerson.PhoneNumber;
        }

        private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _temporaryPerson.Name = txtName.Text;
            _temporaryPerson.Address = txtAddress.Text;
            _temporaryPerson.PhoneNumber = txtPhone.Text;
        }

        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Then this is the Main Form, that is has the LINQ to SQL commands:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Bab_8___LINQ_to_SQL_Classes
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private AddressbookDBDataContext db;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new AddressbookDBDataContext();

        UpdateViewer();
    }

    private void UpdateViewer() {
        dgView.DataSource = (from p in db.Persons select p).ToList();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataForm dataForm = new DataForm();
        if (dataForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            db.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(dataForm.TemporaryPerson);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            UpdateViewer();
        }
    }

    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = (int)dgView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;

        Person selectedPerson = (from p in db.Persons where p.PersonID == selectedIndex         select p).FirstOrDefault();

        DataForm dataForm = new DataForm(selectedPerson);

        if (dataForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            db.SubmitChanges();
            UpdateViewer();
        }
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = (int)dgView.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;

        Person selectedPerson = (from p in db.Persons where p.PersonID == selectedIndex   select p).FirstOrDefault();

        if (MessageBox.Show
            ("Do you want to delete this data?", "Delete Data",
            MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            db.Persons.DeleteOnSubmit(selectedPerson);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            UpdateViewer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really want this problem to be solved.

Comment: Where is the error message? "There is error message"?

Comment: no error but still not working in OK button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the OK's button Property:

```
btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the click not firing when the user clicks on it?